# Mongoose select result based on value of items in database array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema field (prices) which is an array, usually with just 1 price but sometimes with a sale price listed as the second item in the array.

I'd like to be able to query this field and return the all the products, sorted from lowest to highest (and while I'm at it, use $gt and $lt to select by range).

But my challenge is dealing with the sale price, the second value in my array. I need to be able to sort by this price, and not the 1st price if there is in fact a sale price. I don't know how to say "if (prices[1]) { use prices[1] } in my mongoose query.

**UPDATE**

I'm able to get almost what I want using the query below.
My problem is that when I place the bit where price.1 is false first ( the sections are demarcated by the $and) I only get results reflecting products *with* price.1.  When I place the second one first, being that price.1 is true, I only get the opposite, products with *without* price.1.

Is mongoose only reading the second part of my query?

```
Product.find({ $and:
     [{"price.1": {$exists : false }},
     {"price.0": {$gte : req.body.lower_price}}, 
     {"price.0": {$lte : req.body.higher_price} }],
     $and : [{"price.1": {$exists: true}}, 
    {"price.1": {$gte : req.body.lower_price}},
    {"price.1": {$lte : req.body.higher_price} }]}) 
.exec(function(err, products){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        res.send(products)
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a test case for the above problem i.e. for some sample documents, what is your expected output for a given query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.find({$or :[{"price.1": {$exists: false}}, {"price.1": {$gt : 10}}]}) //get all documents where either second element of the price array doesn't exist OR if it does it's greater than 10
    .sort("price.1") // asc. Docs without second element will come first. Use -price for desc
    .exec(function(err, res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            console.log(res)
        }
    });
```